# Moodle API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, moodle, moodle-api

How do i single out the information from the api response to only gather the data from a specific response field?

```js
  var domainname = 'https://sandbox.moodledemo.net';
    var token = '234bc817adf979e93f442946c00aa223';
    var functionname = 'core_course_get_courses';
    var serverurl = domainname + '/webservice/rest/server.php' ;

    var data = {
                wstoken: token,
                wsfunction: functionname,
                moodlewsrestformat: 'json',
                
                }
    var response = $.ajax(
                            {   type: 'GET',
                                data: data,
                                url: serverurl
                            }
                         );
    console.log(response);
```

I am trying to use response.responseJSON[] or response.statusText but I either get an error or unidentified.

How can get the data from the responseJSON field?

[Response output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p65E3.png)

Comment: You need to get the response in callback of [`done`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). `response.done(function (r) {
  console.log(r);
});`

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how r mean responseJSON?

Comment: I just gave an arbitrary name for the parameter, you can give it anything you're comfiratble with

Comment: how would you set the response data to a variable? 
var data2;
          response.done(r=> {
            data = r
            return data2
            
          });
Since this returns null

Comment: Yes you can return the data, instead you could write a function to set the data. No other way :(

Comment: I cant figure out how to do that, I've read the other methods people have tried but all of them dont return any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass an anonymous function to set the data from where the `getData` function is called, inside [`.done`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```js
function getData(fn) {
  var domainname = 'https://sandbox.moodledemo.net';
  var token = '<<token>>';
  var functionname = 'core_course_get_courses';
  var serverurl = domainname + '/webservice/rest/server.php';

  var data = {
    wstoken: token,
    wsfunction: functionname,
    moodlewsrestformat: 'json',

  }
  var response = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: data,
    url: serverurl
  });
  // pass the function parameter
  response.done(fn);
}

// call
getData(function (r) {
    console.log(r, r.length);
});
```

---

Alternative to `.done` you can also use `.then`

Comment: I managed to do it this way         let self = this;
         response.then(r => {
           self.course1 = r[0].displayname;
         }), is there any negatives of using this

Comment: That should be enough as well if you just care about setting the variable

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because at the moment, when you run console at last lines, response hasn't yet came from the server. Since Ajax returns a promise, you can attach a `then()` or `done()` for retrieving the `JSON` data.

```js
var domainname = 'https://sandbox.moodledemo.net';
var token = '234bc817adf979e93f442946c00aa223';
var functionname = 'core_course_get_courses';
var serverurl = domainname + '/webservice/rest/server.php' ;

var data = {
  wstoken: token,
  wsfunction: functionname,
  moodlewsrestformat: 'json',

}
var response = $.ajax(
                      {   type: 'GET',
                          data: data,
                          url: serverurl
                      }
                   );
console.log(response);

response.then(res=>{  //======> Returns data in JSON format
  console.log(res)    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```